# Change the current loggedin Domain?

Tags: 7, redirection, users, sessions

At D7 multi-domain site, how to simply change the current domain of the user after he logged in to another domain?

For e.g, 
A user fill the login form at, "false.example.com", I want to push him into "true.example.com" 
I believe it is the SESSION trick.

Note: I'm using the "Domain Access" module at D7.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your settings.php `$cookie_domain` value.

```
/**
 * Drupal automatically generates a unique session cookie name for each site
 * based on on its full domain name. If you have multiple domains pointing at
 * the same Drupal site, you can either redirect them all to a single domain
 * (see comment in .htaccess), or uncomment the line below and specify their
 * shared base domain. Doing so assures that users remain logged in as they
 * cross between your various domains.
 */
# $cookie_domain = 'example.com';
```

For the session cookie, a value of:

```
$cookie_domain = '.example.com'; // Note the leading wildcard dot "."
```

will work across subdomains

Whereas a value of:

```
$cookie_domain = 'true.example.com';
```

will only work on `true.example.com`

If that session id is valid for that site database session table then the user will be logged in.